# Connect to a device with BLE Android

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect to a device using BLE connection in react-Native on Android Device. 
I need to connect to a device with a with a specific name: for example "deviceName".
I'm using react-native-ble-plx.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';
import { BleManager } from 'react-native-ble-plx';


export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state={
              scaning:false,
              isConnected:false,
              text:'',
              writeData:'',
              receiveData:'',
              readData:'',
              bleManager: new BleManager(),
              data:[],
              isMonitoring:false,

          }
          this.bluetoothReceiveData = [];
          this.deviceMap = new Map();

  }



scan() {
  if(!this.state.scaning) {
    this.setState({scaning:true});
    this.deviceMap.clear();
    const { bleManager } = this.state;
    bleManager.startDeviceScan(null, null, async (error, device) => {
    console.log("scanning bluetooth...")

    if (device.name === "Proximity") {
        bleManager.connectToDevice(device.id, {
                autoconnect: true,
                timeout: BLUETOOTH_TIMEOUT,
                isConnected: true
            })
        // ............
    }
})
  }
}

disconnect(){
        bleManager.disconnect()
            .then(res=>{
                this.setState({data:[...this.deviceMap.values()],isConnected:false});
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                this.setState({data:[...this.deviceMap.values()],isConnected:false});
            })
}

render(){
  return(
    <View>
    <TouchableOpacity
                  activeOpacity={0.7}
                  style={[styles.buttonView,{marginHorizontal:10,height:40,alignItems:'center'}]}
                  onPress={this.state.isConnected?this.disconnect.bind(this):this.scan.bind(this)}>
                  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.state.scaning?'Search':this.state.isConnected?'Disconnect Bluetooth':'Search Bluetooth'}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor:'white',
        marginTop:Platform.OS == 'ios'?20:0,
    },
    item:{
        flexDirection:'column',
        borderColor:'rgb(235,235,235)',
        borderStyle:'solid',
        borderBottomWidth:StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        paddingLeft:10,
        paddingVertical:8,
    },
    buttonView:{
        height:30,
        backgroundColor:'rgb(33, 150, 243)',
        paddingHorizontal:10,
        borderRadius:5,
        justifyContent:"center",
        alignItems:'center',
        alignItems:'flex-start',
        marginTop:10
    },
    buttonText:{
        color:"white",
        fontSize:12,
    },
    content:{
        marginTop:5,
        marginBottom:15,
    },
    textInput:{
        paddingLeft:5,
        paddingRight:5,
        backgroundColor:'white',
        height:50,
        fontSize:16,
        flex:1,
    },
})
```

At the moment I receive this error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.default.startDeviceScan').

How can I fix this error? and do you think the code can work to connect directly to a device? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting BleManager wrong. You have to put it between braces like this:

```
import { BleManager } from 'react-native-ble-plx';
```

You are using BleManager wrong too. You have to instantiate it in some place, I use to use it in the state, to ensure that I have only 1 BleManager and make a new Object of BleManager like this:

```
 constructor {
    ....
    this.state = {
      ....
      bleManager: new BleManager(),
      ....
    };
```

And then use this.state.bleManager instead of BleManager you was using like this:

```
const { bleManager } = this.state;
bleManager.startDeviceScan(...)
```

Comment: Thank for your reply! I have update my post with your advice. I keep getting an "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.bleManager') error

However, do you think this code can work to connect directly to a device?

Comment: You don't have to put the 'const { bleManager } = this.state;'  statemen outside the class. Instead, you should have to put it in the function you use the .startDeviceScan. That should work if your BleDevive is called "Proximity". Anyway you could have more error non founded

Comment: You're right, I brought it in and it tells me that it doesn't find the variable bleManager.

Comment: I found my error! Now the only problem is that i don't know if it works or not xD 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Haha I'm glad you could find your error.  Don't forget to mark that answer as correct if you feel like it.

Comment: Here you have a guide to get started: https://www.polidea.com/blog/ReactNative_and_Bluetooth_to_An_Other_level/

Comment: Oh! Thank you =)

Comment: Get luck and don't forsake! Ble can be a hard world, very undocumented and specially for react native. But once you have the info you would see it is easy!